# Is Build Agent and Deployment Group Are Same?

Tags: azure-devops

I am using Visual Studio Online ( Azure Devops).

I am using On Premise Deployment.

1. When we create deployment group and It provide us some poweshell script and when executed it create window service (VSTS Agent)
2. Other thing is that we download agent pool and configure and run.

Is Agent Pool and Pool that is started using powershell are same ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A deployment group and a normal build/release agent are **not** the same thing. It's the same agent software, but agents registered to deployment groups are for a specific purpose and are not available in the normal agent pools.

Please refer to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=vsts).

Comment: Can I use deployment group agnet for build purpose ?

Comment: No. Deployment groups are for **deployment**.